# How would I structure a class for a universal remote that sends an On/Off command to various devices connected to it?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I want to create a universal remote class where multiple devices are connected to it. I know they wont extend from the remote but unsure how I would send a power off /on command to all of them.

I was thinking like:

```
const tv = new TV()
tv.isOn // gives false
const light = new Light()
light.isOn // gives false
const xbox = new Xbox()
xbox.isOn // gives false
const remote = new Remote()
remote.on()
tv.isOn // gives true
light.isOn // gives true
xbox.isOn // gives true
```

So now if you check like the TV object to see if it was on it would be or the lights etc.

In my head

```
class TV extends Remote
```

sounds dumb. but I cant think of a way where just calling the remote class would change all the other objects. I'm fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since you're asking about OOP design patterns, this is a perfect use case for the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, I will definitely be taking a look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the remote won't help you since you will still have different instances (extending a class will only provide the methods from that class but will not share the state of it with other instances).

A solution for your problem would be to make the `on` (*`toggle` would be a better name to toggle between on and off*) function accept a list of dependencies that would be updated (*you still need to know the instances of the devices that you want to toggle on/off since you need to pass them to that function*).

The toggle function can just negate the previous value `this.isOn = !this.isOn` depending on your needs (right now you control if all of them are on/off, by passing the `boolean` they will all be in sync all the time -- except for when they are instantiated with different states).

```js
class Device {
    constructor(state = false) {
        this.isOn = state;
    }

    toggleState(state) {
        this.isOn = state;
    }
}

class TV extends Device {}
class Xbox extends Device {}
class Light extends Device {}

class Remote {
    toggle(state, devices = []) {
        devices.forEach(device => {
            device.toggleState(state);
        })
    }
}

const tv = new TV();
const xbox = new Xbox();
const light = new Light();

const remote = new Remote();

console.log(tv.isOn);
console.log(xbox.isOn);
console.log(light.isOn);

remote.toggle(true, [ tv, xbox, light ]);

console.log(tv.isOn);
console.log(xbox.isOn);
console.log(light.isOn);
```

Is this what you are looking for?